# when exporting a variable and importing it into another file an undefined error appears, (the paths are correct)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to export a variable from the `movimiento.js` file to use it in`Cita.js`, but before this, I have a file called `index.js` where I want to put all the variables of my files that I want to export to give an order to my application (I am using react)

When I want to use this variable I get the error that `API` is undefined. why?

[image]

index.js

```
import { Movimiento } from "./movimiento";
export { Movimiento };
```

Cita.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, View } from "react-native";
import { STYLES } from "../../../../styles/styles";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Item,
  Icon,
  Button,
  Input,
  Title,
  Left,
  Right,
  Body,
  Content,
  Text,
  Card,
  CardItem,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  DatePicker
} from "native-base";
import { HeaderCitas } from "../../../../Components/Header/HeaderCitas";
import { API } from "../../../../api/";
import { AppointmentList } from "../../../../Components/AppointmentList/AppointmentList";
const Cita = props => {
let citas = API.Movimento.getAppointments();
.
.
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Friend, in this case, believe me that I don't know in any way correct to ask this question. I've tried to be as clear as possible, but I don't know how to put the head of the question. I hope you understand me and can you give me an example. Please do not close my question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder God, I'm a fool .. I forgot to put the code. give me a moment please.

Comment: You're exporting a named export called `Movimiento`, but trying to import a named export called `API`. There isn't one, the name is `Movimiento`.

Either:

    `import { Movimiento } from "etc";`

...or if you want to rename it `API`:

    `import { Movimiento as API } from "etc";`

Comment: If you're not going to fix the question, please delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) said in his comment,

> You're exporting a named export called `Movimiento`, but trying to import a named export called `API`. There isn't one, the name is `Movimiento`. Either: `import { Movimiento } from "etc";` ...or if you want to rename it `API`: `import { Movimiento as API } from "etc";`

If he posts this as an answer, I will delete this, but I feel as though it needed to be posted as an answer.